# Angular reset dropdown values primeng

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Hello comunity I need some help with Angular and Primeng components, the scenario is the next.

I have a model:

```
export class Properties {
    public IdFittingConnector: number;
    public IdProperty: number;
    public IdGroup: number;
    public OrderAparitionNumber: number;
    public OrderCodePos: number;
    public ConnectorDescription: string;
    public PropertyDescription;
    public Values: FittingPropertiesValues[];
    public Disabled: boolean;
    public SelectedData: FittingPropertiesValues;
}
```

This model is stored in an array so foreach item in the array I create an select/dropdown

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arrFittingsCombos;  let i = index">
    <h4>{{item.PropertyDescription}}</h4>
    <p-dropdown [(disabled)]="item.Disabled" [options]="item.Values" optionLabel="IrredutibleFractionValue" [(ngModel)]="item.SelectedData" [showClear]="true" (onChange)="OnFittingComboChange($event)" placeholder="Select Item" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

Like you can see guys, in the model I have a prop that store the dropdown values called "Values" and on the same model I store the selected option on the prop called "SeloectedData".

Now the big deal is the next.

I have a couple of validations and the problem is that I have two dropdowns but if the second value is > the first drop value I need to reset the second dropdown. I show you the logic code...

```
if (selectedOption.IdProperty == 5) {
    let diam: number = this.arrFittingsCombos.filter(x => x.IdProperty == 1)[0].SelectedData.NumberValue;

    if (selectedOption.NumberValue > diam) {
        alert("Seleccion invalida, la selección es mayor que el primer diametro");
        this.arrFittingsCombos.filter(x => x.IdProperty == 5)[0].SelectedData = null;
        this.searchBtnDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

Like you can see I'm resetting the [(ngModel)] and in effect it does but in the dropdown the showed label still exist. What I'm doing wrong? If the first time the validations are ok 
First DropDown Value < Second DropDown Value and after that I change the second dropdown value to > first DropDown value the behavior is the desired one but after that the showed label never reset anymore.

Thanks a lot for you time and I hope you can give me a bit of light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the solution in the HTML I've added the angular identifier:

```
#dropdown_i 

<div *ngFor="let item of arrFittingsCombos;  let i = index">
    <h4>{{item.PropertyDescription}}</h4>
    <p-dropdown #dropdown_i [(disabled)]="item.Disabled" [options]="item.Values" optionLabel="IrredutibleFractionValue" [(ngModel)]="item.SelectedData" [showClear]="true" (onChange)="OnFittingComboChange($event, drop_i)" placeholder="Select Item" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

then in the typescript code I receive the dropdown in the parameter.

```
OnFittingComboChange(event, dropdown: Dropdown) {
  //TODO logic code here...
}
```

finally using a method of the dropdown called `dropdown.clear()` I can reset the picked option.

```
if (drop.value != null &&  selectedOption.IdProperty == 5) {
    let diam: number = this.arrFittingsCombos.filter(x => x.IdProperty == 1)[0].SelectedData.NumberValue;

    if (selectedOption.NumberValue > diam) {
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'warn', summary: 'Validación', detail: 'Seleccion invalida, la selección es mayor que el primer diametro' });
        drop.clear(null);
        this.searchBtnDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

now when the condition is ok the element is cleared correctly and the behavior is the desired.

Answer (score 0):

**why this doesn't work**

This is because you are mutation the property `SelectedData` on a **new** `array`.

Calling `.filter` on an array always returns a filtered copy of the array. So when you mutate this, the ngModel isn't aware of it.

**possible solution**

I work mostly in react so I'm not sure if mutating a property on your class instance is "accepted" by angular. But lets assume it is...

What you can do is replacing the `arrFittingsCombos` with your mutated array, like so:

```
const newArray = this.arrFittingsCombos.filter(x => x.IdProperty == 5)

newArray[0].SelectedData = null

this.arrFittingsCombos = newArray
```